# How do I transform array in search or elsewhere in dashboard

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I have a search that is working fine

```
index=event_db environment=prod release = 2020150015 
| timechart count as Events
```

However, I'd like to modify this to search for any release in an array of releases. I'm aware of the "in" operator.

The catch is that the array of releases I've been provided ("Releases") is formatted slightly differently like so:

```
[ver2020.15.0015, ver2020.15.0016, ver2020.22.0019]  // in general, many more than 3!
```

Is there a way to use the in operator and some mapping to get
release in

```
[2020150015, 2020150016, 2020220019] ?
```

Can this be put in the search?

This is part of a panel so if it's simpler I could have code elsewhere to convert `[ver2020.15.0015, ver2020.15.0016, ver2020.22.0019]` into `[2020150015, 2020150016, 2020220019]`

However, as mentioned I'm a newbie so my knowledge of where to put code to transform an array is limited :)

I have a fieldset section and a panel with a query in it.

The "Releases" array is populated in the fieldset section as so:

```
<input type="text" token="Releases">
  <label>Release or Releases</label>
  <default>*</default>
</input>
```

The user enters ver2020.15.0015 or perhaps ver2020.15.*.

I can't just have the user enter 2020150015 as the ver2020.15.0015 format is used elsewhere.

Perhaps there's a way to create new field `Releases_Alt` right after getting this?

Let me know of any other info I can provide. As I said, I'm new to Splunk so I'm still struggling with terminology.

Comment: How many possible releases are there?  Are all releases known in advance?

Comment: @RichG Possibly hundreds of releases. The Releases is input by the user (see "Input type" above). He/she could enter ver2020.15.0015 or ver2020.15.0015, ver2020.15.0016 or ver2020.* or something else. I could ask them to simply enter 2020150015 and that would certainly work for this query. However, the other format ver2020.15.0015  is needed by other queries in other panels. We are making use of two different indexes index=event_db and index=other_db and you guessed it, they keep the release version in different formats :)

Comment: I'm trying to get a feel for whether or not the release names input could be a multi-select populated by a lookup file.  The lookup file would have both release name formats and the query would use the one that makes sense for that panel.

Comment: @RichG If I understand correctly, that seems promising. I'm new to Splunk. I'll have to figure out how you create, populate, and use a lookup file. Do you have examples? Thanks

Comment: My idea was some sort of lookup function. After all, we just need to remove '.' and 'ver' from each release.  And then a map that maps [ver2020.15.0015, ver2020.15.0016, ver2020.22.0019] to [2020150015, 2020150016, 2020220019]  via a map that uses the function to remove '.' and 'ver'.  I've seen mention of all these separate idea in Splunk (Trim, Map, function) but I'm having trouble putting it altogether.

Comment: If the mapping is that simple then regular expressions may work.  Use this to remove "ver" and dots: `<eval token="Releases">replace ($Releases$, "[ver\.]+","")</eval>`.

Comment: @RichG I feel like I'm close, I have
index=event_db environment=prod release IN (<eval token="Releases">replace ($Releases$, "[ver\.]+","")</eval>) | timechart count as Events
However, I get:
" Error in 'search' command: Unable to parse the search: Right hand side of IN must be a collection of literals. '<' is not a literal."
Can you write an answer (so I can accept) with correct syntax? That is, assuming I can do this eval trick directly in a search query. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies for the confusion.  The XML syntax (`<eval>... </eval>`) is used in the dashboard source code within the `<input>` element.  An `eval` command in a query does not use angle brackets.   Please see if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query.  It uses a subsearch to build the `IN` argument.  Subsearches in Splunk run before the main search and the output of the subsearch replaces the subsearch itself.

```
index=event_db environment=prod release IN ( 
    [ | makeresults 
    | eval Releases=replace ($Releases|s$, "[ver\.]+","") 
    | return $Releases ] )
| timechart count as Events
```

The `makeresults` command is there because even subsearches have to start with a generating command.  `makeresults` creates a "dummy" event that allows other commands to work.

The `eval` command does the work of converting release versions into the desired format.  Note the use of `|s` with the Releases token.  This construct ensures the contents of the token are enclosed in quotation marks, which is expected by the `replace` function.

Finally, the `return` command with `$` returns the results of the `eval`, but without the field name itself.  Without it, the subsearch would return `releases="2020150015, 2020150016, 2020220019"`, which wouldn't work.

Comment: I get a "Unknown search command 's'." message. Pretty sure it's related to the "|s" as removing it gives "No results found." but query runs.

Comment: Use the `|s` in a dashboard.  When running the query interactively, use `"$Releases$"`.

Comment: Works great! Thanks for all your help.  Very gratefully marked as answer!

Comment: Incidentally, I tried your initial idea of putting things in the dashboard source. I added an <init> section with <set token="NewReleases">Garbage</set> .  Then in change section of input, I put  <eval token="NewReleases">replace ($Releases$, "[ver\.]+","")</eval>
With no |s I get results, but periods are not removed. With |s I get no results whatsoever.  Anything immediate come to mind?  My idea was to then use NewReleases in query itself. I say there was no periods removed based on using NewReleases as title of a panel.

Comment: Try `"$Releases$"`.